# How to read in a pandas data frame to a kaplan meier curve?

Tags: python, survival-analysis

I am trying to replicate the Kaplan Meier table that is figure 1 [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/survival-analysis-intuition-implementation-in-python-504fde4fcf8e). The figure is:

[image]

This is the code I wrote:

```
# Python code to create the above Kaplan Meier curve
from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                'T':[0,0,0,0,0,0,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6],
                'E':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
})
## create a kmf object
kmf = KaplanMeierFitter() 

## Fit the data into the model
kmf.fit(df['T'], df['E'],label='Kaplan Meier Estimate')

## Create an estimate
kmf.plot(ci_show=False)
```

My output plot is different (see the scale):

[image: here]

When I print the survival function, it is different:

```
          Kaplan Meier Estimate
timeline                       
0.0                      1.0000
2.5                      0.9375
4.0                      0.7500
5.0                      0.6000
6.0                      0.6000
```

I presume I didn't translate the data into a dataframe properly (possibly?). I tried to mess around with the dataframe, adding the 1 event to the start and end of the time frame, but it didn't matter. Can someone show me how to replicate the example I'm trying to work on?

Comment: Judging from the figure, there are only six users, so: `df = pd.DataFrame({'T':[5, 6, 6, 2.5, 4, 4], 'E':[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]})`

Comment: At the end of the second interval ending at 4.0, there are 2 events. The table in the original is wrong in that respect, or the table is right and the diagram and plot are wrong. Your plot looks correct based on the diagram as far as showing 2 events at 4, but your denominator seems off, There are 2 survivors so there should be a trailing line at 0.33. Just because you see something on the Internet doesn't mean it's right.

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @Arne is correct. There are 6 subjects, so there should only be 6 elements in your `T` and `E` vector. Recall that each element of these vectors is a single subject. `T` represents how long that subject was observed for, and `E` represents if the subject's "death" was observed or not.

Somewhat related, you can make convert from survival table to T, E vectors using a utility function in the lifelines library:

```py
from lifelines.utils import survival_events_from_table

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"observed": 1, "censored": 0, "time": 2.5},
    {"observed": 2, "censored": 0, "time": 4.},
    {"observed": 1, "censored": 0, "time": 5.},
    {"observed": 0, "censored": 2, "time": 6.},
])
df = df.set_index("time")

T, E, W = survival_events_from_table(df)

kmf = KaplanMeierFitter().fit(T, E, weights=W)
kmf.plot()
```